# How to map C integer to Java enum via JNA using TypeConverter?

Tags: java, jna

I would like to have the conversion made by JNA automatically. Right now I'm following the solution from the second answer [in a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157817/how-to-map-enum-in-jna) and JNA's own [EnumConverter](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/EnumConverter.java) utility class. There's one crucial difference, my enum has a constructor argument.

My code defining the `TypeConverter`:

```
public class SentinelStatusConverter implements TypeConverter {
    @Override
    public SentinelStatus fromNative(Object nativeValue, FromNativeContext context) {
        Integer code = (Integer) nativeValue;
        return SentinelStatus.fromCode(code);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer toNative(Object value, ToNativeContext context) {
        SentinelStatus status = (SentinelStatus) value;
        return Integer.valueOf(status.getCode());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Integer> nativeType() {
        return Integer.class;
    }
}

public class SentinelTypeMapper extends DefaultTypeMapper {
    public SentinelTypeMapper() {
        addTypeConverter(SentinelStatus.class, new SentinelStatusConverter());
    }
}
```

Here's code directly registering the native C library along with my custom `TypeMapper`. C functions return an `int` which I want to map automatically into a `SentinelStatus` enum:

```
public class SentinelLibrary {
    static {
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, new SentinelTypeMapper());
        Native.register(NativeLibrary.getInstance("libnamelib", options));
    }

    public static native SentinelStatus hasp_get_sessioninfo(
        NativeLong sessionHandle,
        String query,
        PointerByReference info);
}
```

`SentinelStatus` is an `enum` like so:

```
public enum SentinelStatus {
    HASP_STATUS_OK(0),
    HASP_SOME_ERROR(13),
    ...
    HASP_NOT_IMPL(1831);

    private final int code;

    SentinelStatus(final int code) { this.code = code; }

    public int getCode() { return this.code; }

    public static SentinelStatus fromCode(final int code) {
        for (SentinelStatus status : EnumSet.allOf(SentinelStatus.class)) {
            if (code == status.getCode()) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return SentinelStatus.HASP_NOT_IMPL;
    }
}
```

With this JNA mapping and converter I get an error whenever I try to load the `SentinelLibrary` class:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Structure field type class package.name.SentinelStatus
at com.sun.jna.Structure$FFIType.get(Structure.java:1851)
at com.sun.jna.Structure$FFIType.get(Structure.java:1806)
at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1438)
at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1165)
at package.name.SentinelLibrary.<clinit>(line with Native.register() call)
```

I've read the documentation and there weren't any restriction as to the mapped class or type. Only the `NativeMapped` interface required the implementer to provide a public no-argument constructor.

Is it possible to map a C integer to an enum this way?

**UPDATE:**
After further rummaging through JNA code, I've added this field to the `SentinelStatus` enum:

```
public final static TypeMapper TYPE_MAPPER = new SentinelTypeMapper();
```

Now `SentinelLibrary` gets loaded without errors. But all methods returning the enum, return `null` with error printed to `stderr`:

```
JNA: unrecognized return type, size 4
```

Comment: It could possibly be useful to have the location where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are defining your `Structure` outside the context of your library definition (which is where the `TypeMapper` information is stored).

You can either explicitly set the type mapper on your `Structure` class, or define your `Structure` class within your native `Library` class.  If there is no `TypeMapper` explicitly defined for a `Structure`, it will fall back to the options provided by any surrounding `Library` class.

```
public class MyStructure extends Structure {
    public MyStructure() {
        setTypeMapper(new MyTypeMapper());
    }
}
```

Alternatively,

```
public interface MyLibrary extends Library {
    public class MyStructure extends Structure {
    }
}
```

Or with direct mapping:

```
public class MyLibrary implements Library {
    { Native.register(...); }
    public class MyStructure extends Structure { }
}
```

When a `Structure` class fails to find an explicitly-set type mapper, it looks for enclosing class of type `Library`, and attempts to look up the options used when instantiating that class.  These options get cached when the native library is loaded, so the are available via key lookup using the `Library` subclass as key.  You'll need to implement the `Library` interface so that your direct-mapped library is recognized as a native library class.

**EDIT**

This is a bug in JNA's type mapper handling (see [project issue](https://github.com/twall/jna/issues/467)).  This seems to be restricted to direct-mapped libraries and `enum` type mapping.

**EDIT**

There are several JNA bugs at work here, a [fix is available](https://github.com/twall/jna/tree/issue-467-direct-enum-type-mapping) if you'd like to try it.  This issue is isolated to type mappers on direct-mapped libraries where a primitive is being converted to a Java object.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. It explains why my `SentinelStatus` may not be recognised when `register`ing the library. But the problem still exists. `SentinelStatus` which I want to map to is an `enum`. I can't really make it a subclass of a `Structure`.

Comment: `SentinelStatus` is being used as a field within a `Structure`, according to your error.  It's the `Structure` container that needs to be able to find the type mapper.

Comment: Its also possible that the library caching happens after the `Structure` lookup happens, in which case you'd need to follow the first example and set the type mapper on the structure instance explicitly.  It'd help if you included more of your library definition, particularly those bits that include the `Structure` usage.

Comment: `SentinelStatus` enum is actually only used as a return type of `native` methods from `SentinelLibrary` (as can be seen at the end of the first code block). I'm not using any `Structure` subclasses anywhere.

Comment: Then there's a bug in the JNA error reporting, apparently.