# JNA can not pass Integer as Enum in method

Tags: java, c, enums, jna

I have an method here

```
HRESULT GetImage(
  SIZE    size,
  SIIGBF  flags,
  HBITMAP *phbm
);
```

which takes SIIGBF as an parameter.
SIIGBF is an enum you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitemimagefactory-getimage).

As described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157817/how-to-map-enum-in-jna) I create the enum like this:

```
public static interface SIIGBF {
        public static final int SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT = 0x00000000;
        public static final int SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK = 0x00000001;
        public static final int SIIGBF_MEMORYONLY = 0x00000002;
        public static final int SIIGBF_ICONONLY  = 0x00000004;
        public static final int SIIGBF_THUMBNAILONLY  = 0x00000008;
        public static final int SIIGBF_INCACHEONLY  = 0x00000010;
    };
```

I mapped the method at the top so:

```
WinNT.HRESULT GetImage(WinUser.SIZE size, int flags, WinDef.HBITMAP phbm) {
        return (WinNT.HRESULT) _invokeNativeObject(3,new Object[]{getPointer(),size,flags,phbm},WinNT.HRESULT.class);
    }
```

I run the method like this:

```
WinNT.HRESULT hr = factory.GetImage(size,Shell32Extra.SIIGBF.SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT,hbitmap);
```

But it returns an Invalid memory access error and maybe it`s because of the enum that put in as an Integer. Can you please help me.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Your code contains no enum.  Your `SIIGBF` is an interface with a bunch of `static final int` members, which is not the same thing at all -- neither analogous to a Java enum nor to a C or C++ enum.

Comment: In any case, I don't see much here that we could use to formulate an answer.  Our usual expectation is that questions such as this will include a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnBollinger As I said above I mapped the entire after this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157817/how-to-map-enum-in-jna

Comment: You were right but can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348991/jna-invalid-memory-access-unknown-interface